# Using sz (ZMODEM protocol file transfer) non-interactively

Tags: zmodem

How to use sz command (send files using ZMODEM) non-interactively. I want run a script to transfer a file from unix server to winodws from fixed source directory to fixed destination directory.
The sz manual page says

`With ZMODEM AutoDownload enabled, Professional-YAM  and ZCOMM will automatically recieve
       the files after performing a security check.`

But I'm not getting how to use it.